# Issue with batch files that use the "for" condition

Tags: batch-file

It seems I'm having a problem executing the command ending with an error. Would someone be able to help me with this?

```
for /f "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\SER DATA\*Software*"') do ( 
echo Found %G
icacls "%G" /remove "SER.LOCAL\Admins":F /Q /C /T
)
```

Comment: Try removing `echo Found %G` for starters and see what happens. Also, the variable should be `%%G` in batch file and `%G` when run from command line. So double percent sign for actual batch file and single percent sign for in command line.

Comment: The error below is being displayed. 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: `C:\SER DATA\*Software*` is not a valid use of wildcards.